# Caldera Forms and Smart Groups

Tags: wordpress, smartgroups, caldera-forms

I want to have a newsletter signup form that has a dropdown field that a non-signed in user can select from. I want their selection to assign them to a smart group for later use in bulk mailings. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Jsgoti, Welcome to CiviCRM SE. You definitely achieve this using Caldera module. All you have to do is

1 - Create a form with First Name, Last Name and Email field and also drop down in Caldera form.

2 - Click on Processor tab.

3 - Add a new processor of type 'CiviCRM Group'.

[image]

4. Then configure the settings to link contact to group
   [image]
5. Add condition by clicking condition tab to add to group based on selection.
   [image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I don't understand. Why not just add the Custom Field, and then make the Smart Groups based on the options in that Custom Field directly via CiviCRM? Otherwise it seems you are adding them as static contacts to a Smart Group

Comment: I found this after I posted my question. Examples show both methods you mentioned. Thank you both! https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm/blob/master/docs/examples/subscriptions.md